# Simple code to force cache reload across browsers

Tags: browser-cache

Several testers are seeing cached versions of my webpages, and this is unacceptable.

Please trust me: I have searched for a simple, coherent solution for 2 hours. I am not a programmer, just someone who must deliver the latest version of a website to about 400 visitors, every single time they visit it. Every article I have found conflicts with every other, and none have provided a simple, basic tutorial for casual coders like me.

I just need to know what the exact syntax is for forcing a user's browser to reload the latest version of my HTML webpage, that will work across all browsers, and I need to know exactly where to place the code in that HTML page. Maybe a fiddle?

I apologize in advance for my ignorance, and express profuse thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Comment: That post, which I read about a dozen times, does not contain the simple code I asked for. But thanks.

Comment: Maybe all problems don't have simple answers? Since you've read the post several times you must have picked up that the answer depends on the server software and/or the server-side programming language you're using (which you're not mentioning here) and the top-voted post contains 3-line code solutions to almost all options, which seems pretty simple to me.

Comment: Actually, there seem to be a few - I just need syntax and insertion point. Coding for dummies, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Sorry - I should have read your response more carefully. Yes there are code solutions - I just need to be walked through where to put each. You know - coding for dummies. Do they go between the <head> tags? Are <script> tags required before and after? Etcetera